# How do I remove an existing built package from a PPA?

Tags: ppa

Is it possible to drop built package from a PPA ? Without dropping the whole PPA ?

There's multiple package inside (not multiple version), I just want to remove one of them.

Comment: Drop how, remove from use, or just remove that individual version?  You could always upload a fixed replacement version to overwrite the version already there...

Comment: @LordofTime remove all existing version of that package from PPA

Comment: with the intent to overwrite later with a newer version number?  There's no way to purge a package in a PPA and then upload a lower-version number, if that's what you're asking.  Note that any .deb's already installed on any machines using the PPA won't have that package removed.

Comment: @LordofTime it's too bad if I couldn't upload a lower version..I did the silly thing to re-initialized the bzr reposiroty

Comment: @LordofTime you're right about this, I can't have the package in people's computer removed, i'll just do some trick to increase the revision number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delete packages individually from a PPA. Here, we will delete the *mtr-0.82-3* package from my *Sandbox1* PPA:

1. Click on the PPA from your Launchpad page:

   [image]
2. Click on *View package details* on the top right:

   [image]
3. Click on *Delete packages* on the top right:

   [image]
4. Tick the package(s) you want to delete, and an optional comment. Then click the *Request Deletion* button:

   [image]